# Userdata separation in MySQL, active users and Personal ID

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications, normalization

I am working on a web application and have a few questions about database structure. Here is the structure of the database:
table **user**:

- id
- username
- password
- name (separated in 3 columns)
- city
- gender
- active (which should probably be changed to status)

I tried not to list all the columns but I hope you get the idea. There is another table called **tempuser**:

- user_id
- verification code
- time-sent

I use this to table in the email verification process and after that i delete the record in **tempuser**, and set **"active"** in **table user to 1**.

I wanted to add Personal ID for each user. That should be an 8-digit number separated with dash. EX: 26-391-693. I will use it to save the files uploaded by the users. It should be something like the UCAS Personal ID.

My questions are: Is it good to put the PID column in the user table? Should I seperate the "human friendly userdata" from the metadata in table user?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you have to add PID column in user table because it is unique for each user.

Comment: what about the separation of the data?